# Elegant assert that function is not called from several threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

I have a function that must not be called from more than one thread at the same time. Can you suggest some elegant assert for this?

Comment: What one considers "elegant" is entirely opinion-based.

Comment: `std::mutex` with try_lock

Comment: feels like an atomic increment / decrement of a global would be helpful

Comment: What do you mean by wanting to assert it, anyway?

Comment: @pm100 then not global but static function scope

Comment: What do you mean by "not called from more than one thread at the same time?" Do you mean at the same literal time, or that only one thread should ever call the function regardless of when? If the former you should use some sort of lock/mutex. If the latter you can just inspect the id of the thread calling the function, or just put the function only in the scope of one thread (if possible).

Comment: @Slava - yes you are correct

Comment: It is not thread safe because it uses static member. If someone will try to use it in, for example in parallel for it will not work properly. I just have trouble with such kind of function and want to add assert or check, I don't want to use locks, because now it is used only from one thread. But tomorrow someone can try to use it and will have troubles. On the other hand there are functions that are "thread safe".

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius in most cases elegant mean - short and clear

Comment: What do you want to do in case the assertion is violated?

Comment: @SergeyA dbg break or just throw exception

Comment: If this is the case, just use mutex with try lock and throw an exception if it doesn't succeed

Comment: If you do not want to introduce overhead into sequential code, use some form of locking policy classes with empty default code and member variables. Or, you can conditinally compile and introduce `static` `mutex` or `atomic` counter based on `NDEBUG` existence.

Comment: This sounds like an attempt at coding around a design error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a thin RAII wrapper around `std::atomic<>`:

```
namespace {
    std::atomic<int> access_counter;

    struct access_checker {
        access_checker() { check = ++access_counter; }
        access_checker( const access_checker & ) = delete;
        ~access_checker() { --access_counter; }
        int check;
    };
}


void foobar()
{
     access_checker checker;
     // assert than checker.check == 1 and react accordingly
     ...
}
```

it is simplified version for single use to show the idea and can be improved to use for multiple functions if necessary

Comment: Probably even assert inside the constructor. I would also make the counter a static member of the struct to prevent tinkering.

Comment: The only drawback is that this will introduce overhead into sequential code that uses the function. But it can be easily transformed into policy-based design and define do-nothing policy as default.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need a mutex. Assuming you are using `std::thread` you can look at the coding example in the following link for specifically using `std::mutex`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/mutex/mutex/

```
// mutex example
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <thread>         // std::thread
#include <mutex>          // std::mutex

std::mutex mtx;           // mutex for critical section

void print_block (int n, char c) {
  // critical section (exclusive access to std::cout signaled by locking mtx):
  mtx.lock();
  for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { std::cout << c; }
  std::cout << '\n';
  mtx.unlock();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread th1 (print_block,50,'*');
  std::thread th2 (print_block,50,'$');

  th1.join();
  th2.join();

  return 0;
}
```

In the above code `print_block` locks `mtx`, does what it needs to do, and then unlocks `mtx`. If `print_block` is called from two different threads, one thread will lock `mtx` first and the other thread will block on `mtx.lock()` and be force to wait until the other thread calls `mtx.unlock()`. This means only one thread can execute the code between `mtx.lock()` and `mtx.unlock()` (exclusive) at the same time.

This assumes by "at the same time" you mean at the same literal time. If you only want one thread to be able to call a function I would recommend looking into `std::this_thread::get_id` which will get you the id of the current thread. An assert could be as simple as storing the owning thread in `owning_thread_id` and then calling `assert(owning_thread_id == std::this_thread::get_id())`.

Comment: The function is not intended to use from several threads but can be used accidentally, because the environment is highly parallel. I don't need locking. That should be a check or contact that it shouldn't be used from several threads.

Comment: @BransDs to reliably check for multithread access reliably you have to use threading primitives, either mutex or atomic

Comment: I see. I assumed you meant the former of what I interpreted your question could mean in the OP. I edited in the case for the latter interpretation, which it seems was your intention to ask. Hope that helps.

Comment: OP doesn't wan't simultaneous access, OP wants to make sure it doesn't happen. Your mutex solution doesn't address this.

Comment: I like the idea of thread ids, however, note that you need to protect reads and writes of `owning_thread_id` by a mutex. Otherwise, there would be a data race.

Comment: @SergeyA I actually think I did address it in the last paragraph.